# IonCube Loader caused named service to fail

Tags: linux, centos

I have a VPS (with OVH.com) running Vesta cp. I recently installed IonCube Loader (to run boxbilling) with success.

I believe it was because of this that my named services now fail to restart, however I cannot be sure. But ever since I installed IonCube Loader they have been functioning incorrectly.

The error I get is: zone [domain].com/IN: loading from master file /home/admin/conf/dns/[domain].db failed: file not found.

I get this with all of my domains I have currently registered with Vesta. Just in case you need it, I run the nameservers through cloudflare before they are forwarded to my VPS.

Comment: Problems with named will be nothing to do with installing PHP extensions such as the ionCube Loader.

Answer (score 1):

BoxBilling version 4+ does not require IonCube loader plugin.

You can download [latest BoxBilling release from github](https://github.com/boxbilling/boxbilling/releases/latest)

Update from 3.6 to 4 can be tricky.